# Craft Commerce 2: PayPal Express not working - Correlation id: unknown

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, payment

I try to get PayPal Express running but have quite some difficulties. 
I use the default templates for testing and can get through the whole checkout and payment process, but then PayPal closes and in the console I see the following

```
http.js:114 PaypalUncaught Error: Request to post http://xxx.local/index.php?p=actions/commerce/payments/complete-payment&commerceTransactionHash=xxx&token=xxx&PayerID=xxx failed with 400 error. 
Correlation id: unknown   
{"error": "Es ist nicht möglich, Ihre Dateneingabe zu prüfen."}
```

The error message can be translated to: It's not possible to check your data input.

In my Craft config, I changed the token name, as described here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-paypal

Any ideas what the reason for this could be?

Answer (score 2):

The Craft support helped me to figure this out. The problem was, that the CSRF wasn't properly disabled.

So in my config/general.php I have the following:

```
if ( !function_exists('isApiRequest') ) {
    function isApiRequest ()
    {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $query = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

        $actions = [
            'actions/charge/webhook/callback',
            'actions/commerce/payments/complete-payment',

        ];

        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            if ( strpos($path, $action) || strpos($query, $action) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

return [

'*' => [

    'enableCsrfProtection' => !isApiRequest(),
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems 'complete-payment' got renamed from 'completePayment' which is why the code from another post didn't work for me.